# ¿ comparar los elementos de una misma columna de un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame y requiero agrupar en un nuevo DataFrame las filas que cumplan una condición de igualdad entre elementos que se encuentran en una misma columna, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [1009, "Elemento1","125"], 
                    [1007, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [1008, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [1007, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [1010, "Elemento3","-220"],
                    [1009, "Elemento4","-275"],
                    [1011, "Elemento5","500"]]),
                   columns=['Código', 'Columna', 'valor'])
```

necesito llevar a un nuevo DataFrame las filas donde se de que el valor en la columna
Código sean iguales, es decir:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [1009, "Elemento1","125"], 
                    [1009, "Elemento4","-275"],
                    [1007, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [1007, "Elemento2","150"],
                    columns=['Código', 'Columna', 'valor'])
```

Pensaba hacerlo usando `df.loc[i,'Código']` y con un for ir comparando las
siguientes filas pero no me funciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla es el equivalente en SQL a un `group by having count`, es decir, agrupar y filtrar por la cantidad de casos de cada grupo:

```
df.groupby('Código').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).sort_values('Código')
```

Comment: Excelente, no conocia este equivalente a SQL, me funciono. Te agradezco.

Answer (score 3):

Para saber los datos duplicados podemos apoyarnos del método `duplicated()` que nos devuelve un DataFrame de booleanos indicandonos con `True` los datos duplicados. Luego de haber hallado los datos duplicados de la columna `Código` podemos hacer un filtro para obtener los datos que cumplen con el critero

```py
vals = cod[df["Código"].duplicated()]
duplicados = df[df["Código"].isin(vals)]
print(duplicados)
```

Y con eso obtenemos esto:

|  | Código | Columna | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1009 | Elemento1 | 125 |
| 1 | 1007 | Elemento2 | 150 |
| 3 | 1007 | Elemento2 | 150 |
| 5 | 1009 | Elemento4 | -275 |

Esto está ordenado de acuerdo al índice, si quieres lo puedes volver a ordenar según el `Código`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tengo una pregunta. en la primer linea me salio error por el 'cod', tal vez era df, no?

Comment: si, perdón me había confundido >_<

Comment: jaja ok, no hay problema, con el cambio funciono perfecto. Muchas gracias.